# html canvas not filling with colour

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

ive been following a tutorial on how to make a simple canvas. However, the canvas isnt showing up in any colour even though i have followed the tutorial exactly. any help. its bugging me :/

```
<html>

some text here

<canvas id="gamecanvas" width="800" height="600></canvas>]

<script>
var Canvas;
var canvasContext;

window.onload = function() {
   console.log("Hello world!");
   Canvas = document.getElementById("gamecanvas");
   canvasContext = canvas.getcontext('2d');
   canvasContext.fillStyle = 'red';
   canvasContext.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
 }     
 </script>
 </html>
```

edit: Thanks for the help. Solved!

Comment: your mixing `canvas` and `Canvas`. in js case matters

Comment: How this question is getting up votes? How can be a code with mistakes be helpful to someone?

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer that helped you as correct answer

Answer (score 2):

Too many syntax errors.

This is working

```
<html>

some text here

<canvas id="gamecanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>

    <script>
    var Canvas;
    var canvasContext;

    window.onload = function() {
      console.log("Hello world!");
      Canvas = document.getElementById("gamecanvas");
      canvasContext = Canvas.getContext('2d');
      canvasContext.fillStyle = 'red';
      canvasContext.fillRect(0,0,Canvas.width,Canvas.height);

    }     
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have done two mistakes

- You were mixing `canavs` and `Canvas`
- You have wrote `getContext` with a none-capital `c`

---

Dont forget that variables and method-names are casesensitve in JavaScript.

So `canavas` isnt the same variable as `Canavs` and `getcontext('2d')` isn't the same method as `getContext('2d')`.

**Heres a Fiddle in which I have corrected the errors:**

```js
var canvas;
var canvasContext;

window.onload = function() {
  console.log("Hello world!");
  canvas = document.getElementById("gamecanvas");
  canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvasContext.fillStyle = 'red';
  canvasContext.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

}
```

```html
some text here
<canvas id="gamecanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```